# Maximum size of uncompressed 48x48 px image

Tags: image

What's the maximum size an uncompressed 48x48 image can have? I'd like to set up a reference image for debugging.

Comment: What image format and bit depth?

Comment: The maximum size is infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

48 * 48 = 2304

So, (2304 * number of channels * bytes per channel) bytes

Answer (score 0):

W * H * BitsPerPixel

If BitsPerPixel is 32 (Millions of colors), then it would be 73,728 bits.  divide that by 8 to get bytes (9,216).  The actual size would vary between the uncompressed formats a bit, especially depending on their color capabilities.

For Bitmaps, this Wikipedia page mentiones some of the color options: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Recently I wrote a primitive PNG writer. You have to put one byte infront of every line and add PNG as well as ZLIB headers and checksums. I'm not sure but I think you can have RGBA images with 16bit per channel. The raw data would be 48*49*2*4=9.4kB. So I would make sure that you can handle 16kB or so.

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking about compression, I assume that you mean an image file.

The maximum size would depend on the file format and bit depth that you allow.

A 96 bpp TIFF image for example would be 46 kB.

A more reasonable format could be a 24 bbp BMP file, which is 7 kB.